# Why am I getting quota errors when I upload my first video to YouTube using the new YouTube Data API (V3)?

Tags: youtube-api

I was part of the beta before launch, and I noticed the quota levels have increased quite a bit since the removal of the white list.  I tried uploading to YouTube thinking I had the new quota, but my project's quota, created during the whitelist period, hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually increase your quota in the Google API Console.  Here are the details:

1. Log into the Google API console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
2. Select the project you are using with the YouTube Data API
3. Click on the Quotas Tab
4. Click on the button marked "Set per-user limits..."
5. Change the YouTube Data API units/second/user from "2.0" to "30,000"
6. Click the "Update project"
7. Run your app to upload a video and cry tears of joy when it works =)